# VLFeat: ValueError for certain number of clusters in vl_kmeans

Tags: python, computer-vision, vlfeat, vlad-vector

I have an array of size 301 x 4096, for which I want to calculate the VLAD vector.

I tried to do the quantization using

```
center, assignments = vlfeat.vl_kmeans(data,8)
```

but this returns

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

If I change number of clusters from 8 to 2, it works.
I've also tried other numbers, but all of them returned the same ValueError. Except, when setting it to 1, it returns

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Could it be that it has to do with the number of samples in my data?

Comment: It has to do with the number of items returned by the function. If it is more than 2, you'll get `too many values to unpack`, when its less than two, you get `more than 1 value to unpack`.

Comment: + [see this](https://github.com/dougalsutherland/vlfeat-ctypes/blob/master/vlfeat/kmeans.py#L126). It returns a named tuple, which is single object with your stuff in it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid meaning it should be always two? Then how do I specify the other number of clusters?

Answer (score 0):

The sources of this inofficial Python interface to VLFeat is available on [Github](https://github.com/dougalsutherland/vlfeat-ctypes).

The `vl_kmeans` function by default only returns the `centers`, so there is only one value to unpack:

```
import numpy as np
import vlfeat
x = np.random.rand(10, 8)
centers = vlfeat.vl_kmeans(x, 3)
```

The resulting `centers` array will have the shape `(3, 8)`, i.e. a 8-dimensional point for each of the 3 centers.

If you want to obtain the assignments for each of the inputs, you have to pass the option `quantize` to the `vl_kmeans` function. Then, the function does return both `centers` and  `assignment`, and this works as expected:

```
centers, assignments = vlfeat.vl_kmeans(x, 3, quantize=True)
```